# The site should use a Killscreen image for HTTP/500 Server Error pages

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, top-7, site-attributes

As [badp proposed in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/209950#209950), this site should use a [killscreen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_screen) image for HTTP/500 Server Error error pages:

[image: KILLSCREEN!]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should the 404 image be for the site?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97/what-should-the-404-image-be-for-the-site)

Comment: @Arda: This is for 500 Server Error, not 404 Not Found. I edited to clarify.

Comment: Classic. The question is also the answer, and it's awesome. Totally agree with this.

Comment: @VxJasonxV The answer I hope to accept will simply say: "This has been implemented"... With a screenshot containing freehand circles, of course :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[this will be implemented in the next build.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/error/)

Comment: 'bout time...lasers now? :)